# Bézier curves: a detailed explanation of how draw a letter

Tags: examples-counterexamples, interpolation, applications, parametrization, bezier-curve

After I known the background of Bézier curves, I would like to know is you can provide us a detailed example of how to compute the drawing of a letter, using quadratic Bézier curves.

As tell us this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Fonts) a real life application of Bézier curves are the fonts.

> **Question.** Can you provide me a detailed example, and its explanation, of how draw a letter (lowercase, or uppercase) using quadratic Bézier curves? I am asking about all explicit calculations that we need to draw your letter. It is preferred that the example is not simple at all, and not a very difficult example. **Many thanks.**

Comment: See if this helps you: http://learn.scannerlicker.net/2014/04/16/bezier-curves-and-type-design-a-tutorial/

Comment: Many thanks for the tutorial @Rohan

Comment: Maybe helpful : [this PDF](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/hdb_spul/Splines.pdf) .

Comment: Many thanks I am going to read it @HandeBruijn  I am interested in this since I know that behind of these curves, and related to these as Berstein polynomials, there are interesting interpretations.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a glyph composed of several linear segments in black and quadratic Bézier curves in red. The curves join at the black points. The gray points are control points. The geometric data for this glyph is contained in the Times font. It is essentially a sequence of line and quadratic segments and the coordinates of their points.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.